# Cobra hand held 50wxst aftermarket antenna

Tags: antenna, ht, range, citizens-band

I’d like to add an aftermarket antenna to my cobra HH50wxst to boost my range. My only concern is if I got a longer antenna, could it possibly throw off the SWR and damage the radio? I am totally new to this hobby and am afraid to break things. Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello Daniel, and welcome to this site! :-)

Comment: Thanks, glad to join. I am not a ham operator, but I know the HAM guys know a lot about cb

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to buy an antenna designed for use with that handheld, then it should work fine. Otherwise, you need to make sure that you get an antenna designed for the frequencies used by the radio (in this case around 27MHz, or 11-metre band), that has an impedance of 50 ohms, and has a BNC plug on it.

As long as the antenna meets those criteria, it should perform at least as well as the included antenna. For best results, an externally-mounted antenna is recommended if you will be operating from home or from within a vehicle. This is because signals will be attenuated by the walls or your house, or by the body of a car or truck.

This is the case for all radios, including but not limited to: CB, amateur, commercial, government, or emergency services.

Comment: Thanks, i am occasionally operating from home, but this is mostly for being on a walk away from home or camping. I ended up taking the advice you gave and picked up 2 antennas meant for handheld cb radios. Gonna get another handheld too.

Comment: Would it be wise once the antennas come in to hook the thing up to an swr meter and see what I get?

Comment: Measuring the SWR couldn't hurt.  Check and see how the SWR looks for the antenna that came with the radio also.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch Note that for an accurate measurement, you should use the shortest lengths of coax (if any at all) between the antenna and your SWR meter.

Comment: Interestingly, I can't get my meter hooked up to the antenna. The other thing is it would seem that the longer telescoping antenna does not perform as well as the one that came in the box from the factory.